Create a map of different bat locations across two towns using OpenStreetMap
I'm very early on in the project and haven't used QGIS before. To begin with I want to have my project focus on two towns that I can easily jump between without any lag, I'm just wondering if this is possible?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. The title of a Question should also conform to the "no chit-chat" principle stated by the Tour. Ideally, you should formulate your Question, the write a brief subject statement, which summarizes the topic of the Question, and use that as a title. Note that "Is it possible" Questions are poor quality, because they ask the wrong question -- You want to know how it is possible, not get a "Yes".

Hi louis, re-reading your question, I get the feeling there are infact two questions. 1) How do I easily jump between multiple locations in my map. 2) How do I export a map of two different locations ?


To begin with I want to have my project focus on two towns that I can easily jump between without any lag,

I think what you're after are spatial bookmarks, these allow you to jump around between set locations in your map canvas. Regarding the lag, any lag you experience will be due to your datasources (if you're using data from a remote server) or your memory resources (i.e. if you have a lot of layers to render you may have some lag).
Anyway to make a spatial bookmark right click on the interface to see the full list of available panels you should see Spatial Bookmark Manager (select this)

Then in the spatial bookmark manager panel click on the button circled with '1' (You can also just use the keyboard shortcut ctrl + B). Then add a name in thee dialog box '2'. Then there are a few options, but for me the simplest is just using the 'Draw on canvas' button - click on it and then click drag a rectangle around the first location, and then click save. Repeat this for each location you need.

Then you should have a couple of bookmarks saved (visible in the Spatial Bookmark Manager panel). Now, you can just double click on a bookmark to zoom to it.

